# Why is alternative approach to constrained optimization incorrect?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am studying for the math GRE subject test, and my practice exam has a problem that goes as follows:

Find the minimum distance from the origin to the curve $3x^2 + 4xy + 3y^2=20$.

Apparently I was supposed to solve this using Largrange multipliers, and I will make sure to try that as well. But I didn't do that because when I looked at the problem I saw what I thought would be a simpler method of solving it. I noticed that

$3x^2 + 4xy + 3y^2 = 20 = x^2+y^2 + 2(y+x)^2 = D^2 + 2(y+x)^2$

Therefore, in order to minimize the distance, which is equivalent to minimiziong $D^2$, we can simply minimize $f(x,y) = 20 - 2(y+x)^2$. When I take $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$, I get the same 2 equations: $-4(x+y) = 0$, which implies that $x=-y$.

However, it turns out that after plugging this in, this is not the answer. In fact, when you do it with lagrange multipliers, you get that not only is $x=-y$ is a critical point, but also $x=y$. It turns out that x=y is the one that actually yields the minimum.

So my question is, where did I go wrong? Why does my solution method leave out one of the critical points?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best,

Paul

Edit: I have found the problem with my method, and as Nick points out below it is that there are in fact two different ways to complete the square. I have a feeling that something slightly deep is going on here, and if anyone could illuminate further I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize if this answer is not detailed enough as I do not have a thorough solution to your problem myself. But I do believe that you leave out one critical point because the way you create the square is somewhat arbitrary. For example, you could have written

$3x^2 + 4xy + 3y^2 = 20 = 5(x^2 + y^2) - 2(x-y)^2=5D^2 - 2(x-y)^2$

so then you need to minimize $f(x,y) = 20 + 2(x-y)^2$, which gives you $x=y$. That is your second critical point.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the type of answer I was looking for. The method of completing the square is perhaps arbitrary but not completely arbitrary -- as far as I can tell there are only two ways of doing it, and these two ways give the two critical points.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, even though you have probably figured it out too, I just noticed that the function you were trying to minimize actually has no minimum, you found the maximum since it is concave.

Comment: yes I did find that out and also Random Jack pointed that out. I suppose my question should have been more specifically "why am I not getting both critical points?", rather than "why is my solution incorrect?"

Answer (score 0):

If $(x, y)$ is unconditional optimum then it is necessary the solution to $\nabla f = 0$, but in your case when minimizing $f(x, y)$ you still have constrainted problem and $\nabla f = 0$ is not the necessary condition for the optimum in such kind of problem. Also note that the solution $x = -y$  of $\nabla f = 0$ is the global maximum for $f(x, y)$.

So you go wrong when trying to solve 
$$f(x, y) \to \min, \text{ subject to } 3x^2 + 4xy + 3y^2 - 20 = 0,$$ as unconstrainted optimization problem 
$$f(x, y) \to \min,\ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2.$$

Comment: I follow what you are saying... in a constrained problem the global max/min does not have to have grad(f)=0. On the other hand I am still confused. If the distance is truly equal to the expression on the right hand side, how is it still a constrained optimization problem? Doesn't it then become just a regular old optimization problem?

Comment: @Paul: It is a constrainted problem since you want to minimize the distance or as you noted equivalently minimize $f(x, y)$ on the set of points of your curve, that is subject to $3x^2 +4xy + 3y^2 - 20 = 0$, which is the constraint. When you have found equivalent function to minimize, the set of constraints have not changed, so you need to minimize $f$ on the curve but not on the whole plane and still have a constrainted problem.

Comment: In other words, you have found equal and more convinient representation $f(x,y)$ of the distance to zero, when points belong to your curve, but minimization is still on this curve. You have used the constraints in order to deduce that distance equals $f$, but that does not mean you can forget about the constraints after that because your transformation of distance equals $f$ only in case if $(x, y)$ belongs to the curve, hence minimization is also only on the curve. Hope this helps!

Comment: but doesn't (x,y) always belong to the curve, since all (x,y) satisfy the original constraint equation?

Comment: @Paul: What do you mean by "all $(x, y)$"? Only the points of the curve satisfy this equation. The main point is that $D^2 = f(x, y)$ only under the assumption that $(x, y)$ is a point of the curve. It means that you can minimize $f(x, y)$ instead of $D^2$, but with constraint "$(x, y)$ is a point of the curve". So you have the same constraints as in the initial problem.

Comment: I am defining all (x,y) as the subset of R^2 {x,y|D^2=f(x,y)}. Just as in the equation x=y, if we do any operations on these x,y we have restricted ourselves to the points that satisfy the equation, the points (x,y) we are referring to here are the points that satisfy that constraint

Comment: @Paul: And you're minimizing $f(x, y)$ on this set, which is the constrained optimization problem. It seems that you don't fully understand the difference between constrained and unconstrained optimization. Sorry, but I really don't know how else can I explain this.

Comment: My point is that a constrained optimization is an optimization that is restricted to some subspace of the original space in question (namely R^2). However this can sometimes be reformulated as an unconstrained optimization on the subspace itself.

Comment: for example, if you ask "what is the minimum value of y such that y=x^2", that is a constrained optimization. However it is the same thing as the unconstrained optimization of f(x) = x^2.

Comment: @Paul: Minimize $x^2 + y^2$ given $(x - 1)^2 + y^2 = 1$. Using your method we have $1 = D^2 - 2x + 1 \Rightarrow D^2 = 2x = f(x, y)$. We have $f_x = 2 \neq 0$. That is because this function has no optimum on the whole plane. So you must solve this as the constrained problem. What I'm trying to say is "this can sometimes be reformulated..." sounds not very convincing. You have asked why you didn't get the second critical point, and I have explained this within the limits of theory and not just plausible reasoning. I am sorry if it was not helpful and clear. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do what you wanted, but you made a bit of a problem for yourself by imbedding the "distance-squared-from-the-origin" function into the constraint curve equation.  Instead, the problem would be dealt with by using the constraint to "simplify" the function expression.  So we might use

$$ 3x^2 \ + \ 4xy \ + \ 3y^2 \ = \ 20 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ y^2 \ = \ \frac{20}{3} \ - \ x^2 \ - \ \frac43 xy $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ D^2 \ = \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ = \ \frac{20}{3} \   - \ \frac43 xy \ \ . $$

As the other posters have said, if one were to use the Lagrange method, we would still need to use this together with the constraint equation, since this result alone (as with the equation you developed) is only one equation in *two* variables.  With the modified function here, the Lagrange equations are
$$ 6x  \ + \ 4y \ = \ \lambda·\left(-\frac43y\right) \ \ , \ \ 4x  \ + \ 6y \ = \ \lambda·\left(-\frac43x\right)  $$ $$ \lambda \ = \ -\frac{9x \ + \ 6y}{2y} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{6x \ + \ 9y}{2x} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 18x^2 \ + \ 12xy \ \ = \ \ 12xy \ + \ 18y^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2 \ = \ y^2 \ \ , $$
with the constraint equation then leading to minimum and maximum distances for points on the curve.

But for a timed test like the GRE (which I hope went well for you, since this is an old question), there is something quicker that can be done.  Since the distance-squared function and the constraint curve equation have symmetry about the origin, the points at which extremal values for the function occur are symmetrically located on the lines $  \ y = x \ $ and $ \ y = -x \ \ . $  The constraint equation, which described a "rotated ellipse" centered on the origin, will then give two pairs of points:

$ \ \mathbf{ y \ = \ x } \ :   \quad 3x^2 \ + \ 4·x·x \ + \ 3x^2 \ = \  20 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 10x^2 \ = \ 20 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2 \ = \ y^2 \ = \ 2 \ \ ; $

$ \ \mathbf{ y \ = \ -x } \ :   \quad 3x^2 \ + \ 4·x·(-x) \ + \ 3(-x)^2 \ = \  20 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2x^2 \ = \ 20 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2 \ = \ y^2 \ = \ 10 \ \ . $

Since all the GRE problem asks for is the minimum distance from the origin for a point on the ellipse, we have $ \ D_{min} \ = \ \sqrt{2+2} \ = \ 2 \ \ . $  (We also have the maximal distance $ \ D_{max} \ = \ \sqrt{10+10} \ = \ 2\sqrt5 \ \   $ and can locate the corresponding points, but those results weren't requested.)

[image]